# Sanity check on Capybara match

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I am trying to write a Capybara test case. The HTML looks like this, obtained by writing out "page.body" to a file:

```
<div class="diet_form"><div class="wrapper_no_arrow">
  <div class="header">

    <form name="diet" id="new-diet">

      <label for="name"> New Diet's Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name" />
      <a id="submit_button" class="button-green">Create Diet</a>
```

I'm trying to work out the correct Capybara match:

```
     fill_in "name", :with => "test diet"
     page.should have_link("submit_button")
```

These 2 statements fail to find the input box and also the submit button. Can someone help me write the correct matcher for this?

Here's the error for the 2nd statement:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_link("submit_button")
   expected link "submit_button" to return something
```

Comment: Are you making sure that the test is on the right page?

Comment: @jason328, thanks very much, yes. I got the HTML from "page.body", printed out right before the 2 Capybara statements.

Comment: I assume the tests are only saying that they can't find the input field and link?

Comment: @jason328, yes, that's right. I added the error message I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test is failing because you do not have a proper link on the page. I would change the line that's failing to

```
page.should have_selector('a#submit_button')
```

Comment: Thanks, @RobertH. I am still working it through but this is good.